# different contents and same sidebar approach?

Tags: sidebar, headers, footer

I have a static header, sidebar and footer and then a varying content for single.php. What is the right approach to put contents in the div=content part? Say I have 3 different pages (article, stuff, registration) with this template.
Can I save them in a php file and then call them like how "get_header()" functions?

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>

    <div id="main">

    <div id="content">
    SOME DYNAMIC AND VARYING STUFF HERE
    </div>

    </div>

    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: possibly start by reviewing http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development; http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Comment: That is where the post body would normally go-- the part you add in the large Visual/Text box on the post edit screen. Are you trying to do something different?